# How do I restrict specific folders for a user with full mailbox rights?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have a problem where Users[1..10] have Full Mailbox Access to UserA's mailbox.

UserA, now wants to restrict access so that all the Users[1..10] have access except to the "Sent Items" and "Deleted Items". In this User2 & User3 should carry on having access as previously requested.

Is there a simple way for me to restrict access to the folder without having to remove the Full Mailbox Right permission and apply each individual's user rights on each specific folder?

Sorry if this has been asked before and answered. I did look but I think Google could not understand my query.

I am doing this via powershell as this will need to be repeated numerous times across multiple mailboxes.

Comment: I think you would be better off asking on ServerFault as they specifically deal with  professional server infrastructure administration.

Comment: Thanks @james-c Guess I will do that now.